# Calculation of Battery Consumption of each running mobile application

Tags: r

Is it possible to find out how much each mobile application consumes the battery per day (using R language) , where I have data collection of the following fields

record_id ,
date_time,
application_name,
battery_level,
battery_status

battery_level (It is a number represents the available percentage of the battery)

battery_status ( status of the battery : charging , discharging , full)

This calculation is based on the collected data.

example of such data :

```
    +-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------+
| record_id | application_name | date_time           | battery_level | battery_status |
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 473849    | viber            | 2015-09-01 21:34:01 | 7             | Charging       |
| 473850    | watsup           | 2015-09-01 21:34:01 | 7             | Charging       |
| 473851    | AccuWeather      | 2015-09-01 21:34:01 | 7             | Charging       |
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps if you expand on your question to show us a sample of your data. And explain a bit more what each line means. Is the data reports every minute? Is only one app running at a time?

Comment: @Spacedman : Spacedman , I have edited my question with sample data , this 3 records are extracted from the data report , data report will be generated at every second , it will record all the current running applications , battery level , battery status.

Comment: @Spacedman : Spacedman , please mention the best way of data collection if my above data collection is wrong.

Comment: @techbrainless if you have concurrently running programs it's going to be incredibly difficult to determine how much battery life is being used by each app. Add in variable rates of charging/discharging etc and it only gets more complicated.

Comment: @scribbles : ok in general ,  Is there away to calculate the battery consumption for each running application , if so how ?  what data to collect ? ...etc

Comment: Your sample data rows all have the same time - does that mean that all three apps were running during that second? Anything more specific about getting battery use data for apps is probably best dealt with on another forum.

Comment: @Spacedman : Yes the 3 apps were running at the same second , you can have multiple opening and running mobile apps at the same time (same second) . so which forum you advise to go to find answer for my question.

Comment: @Spacedman : Spacedman , please mention the best way of data collection if my above data collection is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood that it is not possible to calculate battery Consumption of 
each running mobile application using data collected in my first post.

Let us have another data collection .
assuming that we have the following data , 
cpu usage per each running application and 
memory usage per each running application

as the following

```
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| record_id | application_name | date_time           | cpu_usage_per_app_in_percentage | memory_usage_per_app_in_percentage |
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 473849    | viber            | 2015-09-06 19:23:13 | 5                               | 2                                  |
| 473850    | watsup           | 2015-09-06 19:23:13 | 9                               | 2                                  |
| 473851    | AccuWeather      | 2015-09-06 19:23:13 | 8                               | 4                                  |
| 473980    | viber            | 2015-09-06 19:23:14 | 4                               | 1                                  |
| 474254    | watsup           | 2015-09-06 19:23:14 | 9                               | 1                                  |
| 474323    | AccuWeather      | 2015-09-06 19:23:14 | 9                               | 2                                  |
| 474533    | viber            | 2015-09-06 19:23:15 | 5                               | 2                                  |
| 474536    | watsup           | 2015-09-06 19:23:15 | 8                               | 3                                  |
| 474537    | AccuWeather      | 2015-09-06 19:23:15 | 5                               | 3                                  |
| 474538    | calendar         | 2015-09-06 19:23:15 | 7                               | 3                                  |
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

you can suggest any other way of data collection , the key question is that is it possible to make calculation of Battery Consumption of earch running mobile application ? if so how and what the data to be collected?